# Angular $sce blocking my audio blob src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, audio

I am trying to use angular ngRepeat with the html5 audio tag.
I have the html:

```
    <li ng-repeat="recordings in recordinglist">
        <audio controls ng-src="{{recordings}}"></audio>
   </li>
```

and the js:

```
    $scope.$apply($scope.recordinglist.push("blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/67ecfa65-3394-45a6-8f29-42f3421a2727"));
```

But angular's same origin checking is causing an error to be thrown on interpolation:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{recordings}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/67ecfa65-3394-45a6-8f29-42f3421a2727
```

This just seems silly. It's not interpolating a local resource. I imagine there's a way to do this correctly - or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your URL in `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()` ?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution? I'm having similar issues.

Comment: I cheated. Its was for some prototyping so I just put this in the .config '$sceProvider.enabled(false);'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have the same problem when trying to display a blob src for webrtc video before, and I fixed it by using **$sce** service:

```
angular.module('moduleName', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ctrName', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  $scope.recordings = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordings);
}])
```

You may also [check the doc here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

Answer (score 4):

For me the following solved the problem:

```
$sce.trustAsResourceUrl
```

see SO question with more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem with my blob images... Try this:

Basically it allows any blob image in src

```
app.config( ['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider){   
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(blob):/);

  // another sample to allow diffrent kinds of url in <a>
  // $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto):/);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve this is to create a trusted filter.

```
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
};}]);
```

And Use this filter in ng-src.

```
<li ng-repeat="recordings in recordinglist">
    <audio controls ng-src="{{recordings |trusted}}"></audio></li>
```

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of SCE. You'd probably be better off just disabling it than creating a filter which any html could inject on the page maliciously.

Answer (score 0):

When getting the blob from a file reader, you might have to add `$scope.$apply()` to trigger the watch and bind accordingly.

```
InitRecording = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        audioSRC = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(reader.result);
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(recordedBlob);
}
```

Comment: You don't need FileReader... if you look carefully you see that the user has created a blob url using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`

Comment: Exactly, and in case you are using a FileReader, and still facing the same error with  '$sce', then $apply needs to be called, to trigger the watch variables changes