# How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set the `src` attribute of an iframe from a variable and I can't get it to work...

The markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

    <ul class="">
        <li ng-repeat="project in projects">
            <a ng-click="setProject(project.id)" href="">{{project.url}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <iframe  ng-src="{{trustSrc(currentProject.url)}}">
        Something wrong...
    </iframe>
</div>
```

controllers/app.js:

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {

    $scope.projects = {

        1 : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Mela Sarkar",
            "url" : "http://blabla.com",
            "description" : "A professional portfolio site for McGill University professor Mela Sarkar."
        },

        2 : {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Good Watching",
            "url" : "http://goodwatching.com",
            "description" : "Weekend experiment to help my mom decide what to watch."    
        }
    };

    $scope.setProject = function (id) {
        $scope.currentProject = $scope.projects[id];
        console.log( $scope.currentProject );

    }
}
```

With this code, nothing gets inserted into the iframe's `src` attribute. It's just blank.

**Update 1:**
I injected the `$sce` dependancy into the AppCtrl and $sce.trustUrl() now works without throwing errors. However it returns `TrustedValueHolderType` which I'm not sure how to use to insert an actual URL. The same type is returned whether I use $sce.trustUrl() inside the interpolation braces in the attribute `src="{{trustUrl(currentProjectUrl))}}"` or if I do it inside the controller when setting the value of currentProjectUrl. I even tried it with both.

**Update 2:**
I figured out how to return the url from the trustedUrlHolder using .toString() but when I do that, it throws the security warning when I try to pass it into the src attribute.

**Update 3:**
It works if I use trustAsResourceUrl() in the controller and pass that to a variable used inside the ng-src attribute:

```
$scope.setProject = function (id) {
    $scope.currentProject = $scope.projects[id];
    $scope.currentProjectUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.currentProject.url);
    console.log( $scope.currentProject );
    console.log( $scope.currentProjectUrl );

}
```

My problem seems to be solved by this, although I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

I suspect looking at the excerpt that the function `trustSrc` from `trustSrc(currentProject.url)` is not defined in the controller.

You need to inject the [`$sce` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce) in the controller and `trustAsResourceUrl` the `url` there.

In the controller:

```js
function AppCtrl($scope, $sce) {
    // ...
    $scope.setProject = function (id) {
      $scope.currentProject = $scope.projects[id];
      $scope.currentProjectUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.currentProject.url);
    }
}
```

In the Template:

```html
<iframe ng-src="{{currentProjectUrl}}"> <!--content--> </iframe>
```

Comment: I tried it with $sce as you recommended. It causes the error message to go away, but the src attribute of the iframe is still empty.

Comment: Try using `trustAsResourceUrl`.

Comment: trustAsResourceUrl seems to return the same object as trustAsUrl()

Comment: ...but this one works when I pass it into the ng-src attribute! Thanks.

Comment: @Emerson `trustAsResourceUrl` returns a `$sce.RESOURCE_URL` which is needed for `iframe`/`objects` while `trustAsUrl` returns a `$sce.URL` which is a weaker sort of guarantee (and is currently unused as per [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce)).

Comment: ng-src didn't work for me unless I removed the double curly braces( 
ng-src="currentProjectUrl" )

Comment: @baacke I will be surprised if that is the case, [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) clearly states that for interpolation, one needs to have `{{}}` in the expression. If you don't need to interpolate anything, then you do not need `ng-src` at all, just the `src` attribute will suffice.

Comment: Annoyingly, you have to include `$sce` in the controller code, and can't include it in services.

Comment: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl( works! thanx.. i dnt even knw $sce module is exist and its use.. Angular sucks at this... urrgghh!! i wasted my whole day solving it.. finally i found the ryt solution!!

Answer (score 10):

It is the `$sce` service that blocks URLs with external domains, it is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS, to prevent security vulnerabilities such as XSS, clickjacking, etc. it's enabled by default in Angular 1.2.

You can disable it completely, but it's not recommended

```
angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', [])
   .config(function($sceProvider) {
       $sceProvider.enabled(false);
   });
```

for more info
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 5):

this way i follow and its work for me fine, may it will works for you,

```
<iframe class="img-responsive" src="{{pdfLoc| trustThisUrl }}" ng-style="{
                height: iframeHeight * 0.75 + 'px'
            }" style="width:100%"></iframe>
```

here trustThisUrl is just filter,

```
angular.module("app").filter('trustThisUrl', ["$sce", function ($sce) {
        return function (val) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please remove call to `trustSrc` function and try again like this . {{trustSrc(currentProject.url)}} to {{currentProject.url}}.
Check this link http://plnkr.co/edit/caqS1jE9fpmMn5NofUve?p=preview

---

But according to the Angular Js 1.2 Documentation, you should write a function for getting `src` url. Have a look on the following code.

Before:

**Javascript**

```
scope.baseUrl = 'page';
scope.a = 1;
scope.b = 2;
```

**Html**

```
<!-- Are a and b properly escaped here? Is baseUrl controlled by user? -->
<iframe src="{{baseUrl}}?a={{a}&b={{b}}"
```

But for security reason they are recommending following method

**Javascript**

```
var baseUrl = "page";
scope.getIframeSrc = function() {

  // One should think about their particular case and sanitize accordingly
  var qs = ["a", "b"].map(function(value, name) {
      return encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" +
             encodeURIComponent(value);
    }).join("&");

  // `baseUrl` isn't exposed to a user's control, so we don't have to worry about escaping it.
  return baseUrl + "?" + qs;
};
```

**Html**

```
<iframe src="{{getIframeSrc()}}">
```

Comment: The documentation provides this advice in case one is binding to more than one expression in `ng-src` or `src`. Angular 1.2 onwards, one can bind to only one expression in `src` and `ng-src` and the advice is to retrieve an url from the code using a function, if needed.

Comment: But I think there is some mistake in your code. The controller should be like this app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {});

Comment: Controllers can be [_Globally accessible functions_](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngController) as well.

Comment: Ok. Check this link I checked your code with plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/caqS1jE9fpmMn5NofUve

Comment: I have noticed a function "trustSrc" in your code. Please remove that function and try again like this . {{trustSrc(currentProject.url)}} to {{currentProject.url}}

Comment: The plunker uses Angular 1.0.8?

Comment: @Sajith please see my updates above. I am able to use trustSrc as you have both suggested, but I can't retrieve the URL from the returned object. I tried calling .toString() on it but it went back to throwing the same error from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

select template;
iframe controller, ng model update

index.html

```
angularapp.controller('FieldCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
        var iframeclass = '';
        $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
            if ($scope.template.length > 0) {
                // add iframe classs
                iframeclass = $scope.template.split('.')[0];
                iframe.classList.add(iframeclass);
                $scope.activeTemplate = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.template);
            } else {
                iframe.classList.remove(iframeclass);
            };
        };

    });
    // custom directive
    angularapp.directive('myChange', function() {
        return function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('input', function() {
                // the iframe function
                iframe.contentWindow.update({
                    name: element[0].name,
                    value: element[0].value
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

iframe.html

```
   window.update = function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope[data.name] = (data.value.length > 0) ? data.value: defaults[data.name];
        });
    };
```

Check this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/TGRj2o?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need also `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` or it won't open the website inside the iframe:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.angularjs.org');

    $scope.changeIt = function () {
        $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial');
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="changeIt()">Change it</button>
</div>
```