# Facebook like button using iframe in a AngularJS website

Tags: facebook, angularjs, iframe

I was trying to implement facebook like button using iframe in my AngularJS website. But facebook button is not loading.

```
//html portion
<div ng-controller="FBCtrl">
  <iframe ng-src="{{likeURL}}"></iframe>
</div> 

//controller portion
.controller('FBCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.likeURL = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fflyerbd&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80';
}]);
```

**Basically i want a simplified way to use facebook like button in my website.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`$sce` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#methods_trustasresourceurl) in your controller and recognize the URL as trustworthy:

```js
.controller('FBCtrl',['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.likeURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fflyerbd&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80');
}
```

Related: [How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable/20045301#20045301)
.

Comment: I used it but nothing happened. In fact app crashed. i ran it from my localhost.

Comment: @FahadBillah Define "app crashed"? What was the error produced? Could you post an example?

Comment: its my chrome's problem and i can't determine why this button is not showing in chrome cause no error report shows in my chrome's console(its my chrome's problem again). But your method did work. i ran my site in firefox and everything is fine. like button is showing where it suppose to be. Thanks a lot.