# Create a YouTube AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, angularjs-directive

I created the following AngularJS directive to embed youtube videos:

```
// A Simple youtube embed directive
.directive('youtube', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{code}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
  };
});
```

When I call it from my template `<youtube code="r1TK_crUbBY"></youtube>`, I get the following error:

> Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{code}}
>   Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce

I can't identify what's wrong with the directive in the `{{code}}` expression.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With Angular 1.2, you need to inject [`$sce` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce) and [`trustAsResourceURL`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#methods_trustasresourceurl) the `src` of an `iframe`.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0N728e9SAtXg3uBvuXKF?p=preview

```
.directive('youtube', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
           if (newVal) {
               scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
           }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Also see: [Migrate from 1.0 to 1.2](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable/20045301#20045301).

Comment: I tried the above and I added the missing comma for the end of the template: line, Now it's not giving any error, but it doesn't show the video embedded, inspecting the element I see the src attr empty.

Comment: @JonathanHindi It works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0N728e9SAtXg3uBvuXKF?p=preview with Angular 1.2 How are you using the directive in the template?

Comment: Thanks now it works, I was using the <youtube code="{{code}}"></youtube> I thought I need to pass it with the currently brackets to be evaluated first then pass the actual value to the directive. but it seems that I was wrong.

Comment: You saved me lots of try and error. Thanks @musically_ut