# How to display youtube or vimeo videos in iframe with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, iframe, youtube, vimeo

I just start to using angularjs and I want to display youtube or vimeo video in iframe from the video url, How to display it when people insert video url in input and then click the button.

```
I have created a plunker
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yj3aZ32hemcURHB4CGYX?p=preview

Comment: Hi for youtube maybe this stackoverflow post can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447867/create-a-youtube-angularjs-directive

Comment: thanks for reply but I need to know how to use with vimeo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is the answer.

https://github.com/erost/ng-videosharing-embed

Looks pretty good