# Using an angular expression in an ng-src with google maps embed api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a map on each page that is specific to the values from an api, but I am getting this error message:

Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$interpolate/noconcat?

Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml" class="col-md-4 map">
    <iframe ng-src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/placekey=AIzaSyAJ_lVIxNq31PmzRUbMh9JIStQOE4_6-aQ&q='{{event.venue.name}}'"/>
</div>
```

and here is the controller:

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, EventsFactory, $routeParams, $sce){
    EventsFactory.async().then(function(data){
        $scope.events = data.data;
        $scope.event= findEvent(eventId, $scope.events);
        console.log($scope.event);
        $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`, try using `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()`. Place your *whole URL* as parameter for `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()`. The link below worked for me.

[How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs/20045301#20045301)