# Unable to load url into iframe via AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically load a URL into an iframe via AngularJS. For some reason, I cannot as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4WyL/). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why can't I bind to a URL set in my controller? The code is pretty small:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Trying to load {{ customUrl }}</div>
    <div><iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(customUrl)}}" height="480" width="640"></iframe></div>
</div>

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.customUrl = 'http://www.google.com/custom';
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that your code isn't working is because the source isn't trusted. In order to get the source to be trusted, you need to use the `$sce` service as [recommended in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable). If you do that you end up with the following:

**Html**

```
<div><iframe ng-src="{{customUrl}}" height="480" width="640"></iframe></div>
```

**Controller**

```
function LoginController($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.customUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.cnn.com');   
}
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4WyL/4/

**Edit** - My original answer said to remove the curly braces. This was completely incorrect. The curly braces are required in `ng-src` in order to have the url actually be evaluated. The reason this *seemed* to work is because code that is part of the template is implicitly trusted while variables are not. That said, the url was absolutely not valid - it just tried to load the name of the variable inside of the current page. Hopefully this will help others in the future that try removing the curly braces!

Comment: Hey , drew please have a look on this thread..(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354726/sce-trustasresourceurl-is-not-working/34354982#34354982)thanks