# angularjs ng-src within iframe

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get ng-src to work in an iframe, but I can't seem to figure it out. Is it possible?

```
<div class="row" ng-init="video='http://www.youtube.com/embed/gMW8jUX14Y0'">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" ng-src="{{ video }}"></iframe>
    </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

The page loads a blank iframe and it never refreshes.
on the same page I can include this code and it works just fine.

```
<a ng-href="{{ video }}">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iframe and ng-src have been discussed on SO before with a solution using $sce (to trust the URL for ng-src='URL') 
link: [AngularJS ng-src inside of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163152/angularjs-ng-src-inside-of-iframe) 
link: [Unable to load url into iframe via AngularJS controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634930/unable-to-load-url-into-iframe-via-angularjs-controller) 
link: [How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable)

GL!