# $sce.trustAsResourceUrl is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I am working with iframe in my project just tried to open url inside my app through iframe , but its not working at my end , please have a look and provide your valuable suggestion.I will be very thank full to you .

Here is my controller code :-

```js
app.controller('IframeCtrl', function($http, $scope, $ionicPopup, $state,
  $ionicLoading, LocalStorage, $sce) {

 $scope.customUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.magentomobileshop.com/demo/payu/index/payu?orderid='
   + LocalStorage.getData("orderid"));

 window.checkIframeUrl = function(curentUrl) {
  alert(curentUrl);
 };
 

});
```

My iframe.hml :-

```html
<ion-view view-title="PayU Money"> <ion-nav-bar
 class="bar-positive" align-title="center"> </ion-nav-bar> <iframe
 src="{{customUrl}}" src="http://www.google.com"
 onLoad="checkIframeUrl(src);" scrolling="none" frameborder="0"
 height="600px" width="100%"></iframe> <ion-content> </ion-content> </ion-view>
```

I even try this link :- http://jsfiddle.net/W4WyL/4/

here is what i try now as :-

My conroller :-

```js
 function($http, $scope, $sce) {

 
 var url="http://www.magentomobileshop.com/demo/payu/index/payu?orderid=100000030"
 
    $http.get($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)).success(function(data) {
     $scope.myData  = data;
     
    });
 
}
```

My new Html :-

```html
 <div><iframe
 ng-src={{myData}} frameborder="0"
 height="600px" width="100%"></iframe> </div>
    </div>
```

Okay, i think this might be the issue that payU is a secured Url so this might not be getting open on iFrame but is there any way i can track url in window.open(), so that i can close the webview when i will be on that tracked Url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if iframe is supported by angular logic.
Anyways, instead of the doubled "src" attribute, write

```
ng-src="{{securedUrl}}"
```

Also, it would be nice to put a validity check on the

```
LocalStorage.getData("orderid")
```

value.

Comment: Thanks Redd for your reply , yes i have checked the orderid and its coming..moreover i tried with ng-src too but that also won't helped me :(

Answer (score 0):

Ah wait. I didn't notice you are inflating that value as a query param. 
I don't think it could work in any way.
You are just filling an address, and whitelisting a link, you are not getting the data.

You probably could use

```
$http({
    url : $sce.trustAsResourceUrl( yourURL ),
    method : "GET"
}).then(
   function(data){
      $scope.myData = data;
   },
   function(error){
      // manage error
   }
);
```

Comment: do i need  to do like this in HTML :- ng-src={{myData}} 
 then how will i make check for url

ng-src="http://www.google.com"
 onLoad="checkIframeUrl(ng-src);"

Comment: You have to do something with $scope.myData afterwards.

Comment: Hey Redd , while implementing this in plunker  i am getting this error :-

{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "child \"path\" fails because [path fails to match the required pattern]",
  "validation": {
    "source": "params",
    "keys": [
      "path"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I tried:
    `$http({
        url : $sce.trustAsResourceUrl( "http://www.magentomobileshop.com/demo/payu/index/payu?orderid=100000030" ),
        method : "GET"
     }).then(
         function(data){
               $scope.myData = data;
         },
         function(error){
              // manage error
         }
     ); `

From the plunker. It gave me a CORS error: You must specify the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the remote resource to available for your request host

Comment: Hello Redd , Thanks for your continuous help  , if you are using chrome you can add one plugin to get the rid out off this error , install this chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: I would like to tell you that this url was working fine on  window.open(url, "_system", "location=yes");

Comment: Okay, i think this might be the issue that payU is a secured Url so this might not be getting open on iFrame but is there any way i can track url in window.open(), so that i can close the webview when i will be on that tracked Url.