# ng-bind-html element not working with audio tag

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have a variable in scope **result.questionText** it contains `<i>How many times are the hands of a clock </i>at right angle in a day?<audio controls ng-src="media/abc.mp3"></audio>`
,i want to display html audio component instead of that audio tag so i write like this in my html page,

```
<span class="row pull-left" ng-bind-html="result.questionText"></span>
```

but it is showing text before audio tag but not showing audio component.
I have tried to put img tag and it is working fine.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to use `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable) for examples.

Comment: thanx for comment...but there is no change in o/p.. :(

Comment: If to have a look into angular source, it uses `element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');` in ng-bind-html directive. So you should set the path to audio content ('media/abc.mp3') as trusted at first: `$scope.audioSource = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('media/abc.mp3');` and `<audio controls ng-src="{{audioSource}}">`.

Comment: Also [there is](http://jsfiddle.net/djqck/1/) a fine example of setting `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` via `Filter`. I hope it became clearer now.

Comment: Got the answer `$scope.result.questionText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.result.questionText);` works for me.