# Embed Youtube video in AngularJS generates error when loading the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, youtube

The code snippet below is used to embed Youtube video in my page.

```
<div ng-if="videoUrl != ''" style="height:400px;">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="{{videoUrl}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

In my controller, `videoUrl` is first set to an empty string, and updated once data is retrieved from server.

```
$scope.videoUrl = '';

videoService.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.videoUrl = response.videoUrl;
});
```

The Youtube player works and the URL is correct, I can watch the video with the embeded player after the page is fully loaded. What bothers me is each time when loading the page, an error is returned. I can see from the browser console that it was trying to send a `GET` request to `http://www.example.com/%7B%7BvideoUrl%7D%7D` with its status as `(canceled)`. This request is not something I want and it fails for sure.

How can I get rid of that weird `GET` request?

Comment: I would imagine that when the DOM is rendered, `$scope.videoUrl` is not actually empty, but undefined. Try using a falsey test instead: `ng-if="videoUrl"`. Also, you might need to use `ng-src` rather than simply `src`. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable) answer

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works. Would you post an answer for this question?

Comment: It's better if you post your own answer, you'll know exactly what you changed and what references you used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my code based on RGraham's suggestion and the error is gone now.

First, change `src` to `ng-src` and the checking condition to `ng-if="videoUrl"`.

```
<div ng-if="videoUrl" style="height:400px;">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" ng-src="{{videoUrl}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

Second, I initialize `videoUrl` to `undefined`.

```
$scope.videoUrl = undefined;
```

Now the page loads without sending the previous weird `GET` request anymore.