# Access $scope variable in iframe Url

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am able to access my $scope.token variable in html.

```
{{token}} <!--this works. gives me needed optput-->

<iframe ng-src="http://{{token}}@xxx...." width="100%" id="test">
</iframe> <!--this does not work. gives me error-->
```

I know this must be very simple thing but I am new to this so dont know. If someone know this please let me know How should I use this variable in double quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS: How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable)

Comment: Thanks @DavinTryon I got the answer from the question you shared.