# using angular bindings with google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I want to use a simple google maps embed that utilizes angular bindings to make the map more dynamic. So instead of the following

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=180+N+500+E,+Salt+Lake+City,+UT
&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

I want bindings to be added in the src attribute

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q={{event.address}},+{{event.city}},+{{event.state}}
&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

When I do this I get this error in the console

**Error:**

> $interpolate:noconcat Multiple Expressions

Im not sure what this means.

Comment: I think you have to use the `ng-src` attribute instead of the standard `src`. But I'm not sure... **EDIT:** Maybe you can also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable

Comment: I just tried `ng-src` but unfortunately no change but I will take a look at that question