# How to load iframe in window.open in javascript when url is assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, window.open

In my angular application, I have an url which I need to open in new window. If I directly give url in iframe src, it works. But if the url is stored in an variable and if I assign src through variable, it fails.

For example:
var win = $window.open();
win.document.write('')

This works.

But if I have a variable url = "//www.youtube.com/embed/mTWfqi3-3qU".
var win = $window.open();
win.document.write('')

This fails.

If a url is assigned to a variable, how to assign that url to iframe src?

Comment: you want to open in `newTab` or `Iframe`

Comment: I suppose there's answer on your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable

Comment: No. I need to use iframe in window.open(). Here src attribute of iframe should be assigned from a variable.