# How to retrieve content (element by element) of a external website using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a new AngularJS app. I would like to have something similar to JSOUP functionality but on AngularJS.

Questions :

- How can I get HTML code of a external website ?
- How can I split them by "elements" (i.e : div, span etc...)?

I tried to use $http.get in **app.js**:

```
$scope.test = function(){
    $http.get("https://www.civiweb.com/FR/offre/71087.aspx").success(function(data){
        $scope.test = data;
    })
    .error(function(data){
      console.log("Error getting HTML : "+data);
    });

  }
```

**index.html**

```
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

Not working ...

I hope you can help me, Thank you

Comment: Will not work. You need CORS or JSONP (only GET) activated to receive data via cross origin. Please add your full view. <div>{{test}}</div> is not enough.

Comment: Thank you, I will go for a native app on Android by using JSOUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible idea.

But if you must...

> note: this is for development purposes only, and my solution, will not, and should not, work on other machine but yours.

I would start by injecting the HTML inside a iframe element.

Then traverse the iframe HTML-tree for content.

**index.html**

```
<iframe ng-src="{{remoteUrl}}" > </iframe>
```

**app.js**

```
var init = function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.remoteUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://example.com");
}
```

for more information about [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) please refer to [How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable)

now all is left is to wait for loading the iframe content, and then traverse it.

continue **app.js**

```
myFrame= document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
myFrame.load = function(e){
  myDiv = myFrame.document.getElementById("ContenuPrincipal_BlocA1_m_oCity");
  alert(myDiv.innerHTML);
 }
```

Now for this to work, you must override the Same-origin policy.
(one way is the write your own line in your hosts file... or chrome with flag)

Comment: Ok thank you, Then I will go for a native app. By using common JSOUP on Android :)