# URL structure breaks ng-src?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just trying to put a path and file extension around an expression ng-src like so:

```
<iframe src="'path/' + pattern.anchor + '.html'">
```

which would ideally resolve to:

```
<iframe src="path/name.html">
```

if pattern.anchor is set to "name". I have no problem with the expression showing up elsewhere in my template. If I leave src="{{pattern.anchor}} then I get src="name", which is great but of course not what I need.

Any reason why this is not working?

Comment: You meantioned `ng-src`, why are you still using `src` as the attribute instead of `ng-src`? Using `<iframe ng-src="'path/' + pattern.anchor + '.html'">` instead may fix your issue. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<iframe src="{{ 'path/' + pattern.anchor + '.html' }}">
```

or create the path and assign it to a $scope variable and just point it at that.

You might want to actually use ng-src instead of src. Using src doesn't know to use ng-src, and ng-src will be more reliable, if it works for iframes, which I haven't confirmed.

Comment: Thanks, used ng-src and your suggested code and now I'm golden. Much appreciated.