# Angular: How to make a youtube video with dynamic src

Tags: angularjs, youtube

I have a popup, and I want to show/hide by click image or youtube video`

```
 <img ng-show="showImage" style="width: 430px;"  ng-src="{{images}}">
                    <div ng-show="!showImage" style="width: 430px;"  >
                        <iframe width="430" height="321" src="{{getIframeSrc(idBitches)}}" ></iframe>
                    </div>
```

But something wrong. How can I do it?

Comment: Show us the content of getIframeSrc(), do you have an error in the firebug?

Comment: use `ng-src` so browser doesn't send angular expression to server which obviously won't work. Beyond that there isn't enough information given to troubleshoot anything else

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable