# enbedding Youtube link in iframe using angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I like to post the video link on my website but that doesnot work

```
<div ng-repeat="vid in video">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="250px" height="250px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/+{{vid.youtube}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
```

The above code not working, please help.

Comment: What part of it is not working? Are you getting any errors? One thing i spot is you need to use `ng-sr`c instead of `src` if you want the angular to get evaluated in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the ngSrc attribute as they say in the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) otherwise your browser tries to fetch the url with "{{vid.youtube}}".
Plus you don't need to add a "+", there isn't any on Youtube urls.

**EDIT :** I actually had the same problem with iFrames, and I forgot about it : you must tell Angular you "trust" the Url given. Take a look a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs), it's exactly the same problem.