# Embed Document without extension in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, document

I have a document url which has no extension.
I have used iframe to embed it in my html but its not showing.
`<iframe ng-src="url"></iframe>`
How can I handle such documents in html?

Comment: ..and what the document content type is?

Comment: not able to figure out.In info it is showing text edit document type.

Comment: just open your console network tab and open that url.. then see what is the content-type of the response header. The server should set the content type for the content and then browser can do something with it. For example jpg image comes with `image/jpg` content type when loaded from server and then browser sees "oh there is image, i will render that".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045301/2611927