# How bind external url page to ionic page template

Tags: angularjs

I need bind external page to ionic template with header and menu. Eg. When click in menu to link http://google.com opens state with ionic header and menu but in template body website http://google.com

Comment: you should use an iframe but you need `$sce` for trust the HTML injected

Comment: Can you make example with $sce

Comment: of course. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045301/1374997)