# Unable to load and play video in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I upload a video into my mysql database. i have the location of it.when i try to load that video dont work.

my angular code is given below.

```
  $scope.videoApi = function(id) {      
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://192.168.1.16:8070/courseapi/getpdf",
      data: {
        'id_course': id
      }
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      alert("listapi" + response.data);
      $scope.videodata = response.data;
      //$scope.currentProjectUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.videodata[0].course_Attachments);
        }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.message = response.statusText;
          console.log(response.statusText);
          alert("courseEnrolled");
        });
  }
```

from here i the path of the video

my html code

```
<iframe src="{{videodata}}" width="50%" height="400px" ></iframe>
```

but this not works;

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-src` instead of `src` attribute in `iframe` . Hence remove double braces

```
<iframe ng-src="videodata" width="50%" height="400px" ></iframe>
```

For your reference: [How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.videodata = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k");
```

I think you need to give the url of video in iframe.and the iframe as

```
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="{{videodata}}">
  </iframe>
```