# How to load an iframe in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, x-frame-options

When i put my iframe it says the following error,

```
Refused to display 'my url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY, DENY'.I am using this iframe for the first time.


 <iframe src="myurl"></iframe>
```

Can anyone please help me about the situation.

My ctrl,

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

My html,

```
<iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(https://www.w3schools.com)}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: show the controller code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a function defined and pass the url to it,

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

and in HTML

```
<iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(myurl)}}"></iframe>
```

**Note:** You need to inject   **`'$sce'`** as a parameter to your controller.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$sce){
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<iframe   height="100%" width="100%" ng-src="{{trustSrc('http://www.espncricinfo.com/')}}"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi,sajeetharan.Its not workin I edited my code,can u pls check.

Comment: check the demo attached or this http://plnkr.co/edit/YlWzMyMZcwcLXHLsIQcZ?p=preview

Comment: ,its working for me with your example but when I put my url,it says error  Refused to display 'myurl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY, DENY'.