# Storing Youtube video URL in firebase, and then inserting URL in <iframe> does not display video

Tags: javascript, html

I stored a few youtube URLs in Firebase, and I want to insert them in the html like so:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{main.vid}}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, when running the code it only displays a blank. I am using the correct URL when clicking share and then embed on Youtube.

When I replace the Firebase data URL with the normal one like so:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6CulBuMCLg0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it works fine. Any help?

Comment: So if you do a "view source" on the iframe, what do you see?

Comment: The source is empty. When I go to developer tools, the src attribute is completely missing?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs

Comment: This is a client issue. Where you store the URLs is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using Angular or something similar.

Angular sanitizes URLs before string interpolation for security reasons.

You need to bypass the sanitizer. A possible solution is a custom pipe.

Comment: I disabled the $sceProvider. It is not recommended, but it seems to do the job.

    angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', [])
.config(function($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
 });