# Angular 10: Set IFrame URL Input with Variable

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, angular10

I am trying to set the IFrame Source Input with a component below.

Its not working for some reason, showing no wepages. How can I set the input source properly?

**Calling Method:**

```
<app-viewer-iframe-two
    [url1]="'http://www.food.com'"
    [url2]="'http://www.car.com'"
>
</app-viewer-iframe-two>
```

****Typescript:****

```
export class ViewerIframeTwoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() url1: string;
  @Input() url2: string;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

****HTML:****

```
<div class="box">
  <iframe class="iframe-one" src="{{url1}}" frameborder="0"
    scrolling="yes" align="left"> </iframe>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <iframe class="iframe-two" src="{{url1}}" frameborder="0"
    scrolling="yes" align="right"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Error:**

No source ever gets set,

[image]

**Resource:** this is only for Angular 1

[How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs)

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863439/8198889

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is still non-secure to put whatever into url same as in Angular.js. Just bypass it - it will be still non-secure, but you will take responsibility instead of angular developers.

```
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
```

write as `[src]="urlSafe"`

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: did I set my inputs, and quotes, and brackets correctly?

Comment: It doesnt matter while you try to put random string into src - angular will not allow it.
bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl returns SafeResourceUrl, not string, so dont interpolate it,but put like [src]="urlSafe"