# Can I use Angular variables as the source of an audio tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="audio in event.audios">
    <audio ng-src="/data/media/{{audio}}" controls></audio>
</div>
```

But when I load the view, the {{audio}} variable is not parsed but hardcoded into the source as is. However, if for example, I place that same variable outside of the audio tag it renders the name of the audio file correctly. I've tried using both src and ng-src to no avail.

Is there a way to get the variable to work within an audio tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think this is a different case, in the link you posted the variable he  is using renders fine but the video doesn't plays. In my case the variable is not being parsed. I am also using it within an ng-repeat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, thanks to theJoeBiz's input and some thinking around I solved this by making a directive, here is the code:

```
app.directive('audios', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<audio ng-src="{{url}}" controls></audio>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal, oldVal) {
           if (newVal !== undefined) {
               scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("/data/media/" + newVal);
           }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Then on the template I used it like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="audio in event.audios">
    <div audios code="audio"></div>
</div>
```

It is all working fine now.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>I'm not all *that* familiar with the ngSrc directive outside of using it on images, but it might require an img tag somewhere in the source.</strike>

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="audio in event.audios">
    <audio ng-attr-src="/data/media/{{audio}}" controls></audio>
</div>
```

The ng-attr- directive can be used for any attribute that doesn't have a specific role in angular. You can read more about it on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

**Update, I was wrong.**

I created a jsfiddle and found the actual error that was occurring.

You're getting an error from the sce service. See the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729537/angular-sce-blocking-my-audio-blob-src).

The solution is to use `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()`.

Example:

```
angular.module('AudioTest', [])
.controller('AudioTestCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.event = { 'audios': [
        $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/data/media/test1'),
        $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/data/media/test2')
    ]};
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhFzM/).

**Update #2**

If you don't want to set the url as hard coded or loop through after you get a response from the server, you can use a custom filter to accomplish what you're looking for. This method does not use interpolation, which is where the error is being thrown.

JS:

```
angular.module('AudioTest', [])
.filter('trustedAudioUrl', function($sce) {
    return function(path, audioFile) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(path + audioFile);
    };
})
.controller('AudioTestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.event = { 'audios': ['test1', 'test2']};
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="AudioTest">
    <div ng-controller="AudioTestCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="audio in event.audios">
            <audio ng-src="/data/media/ | trustedAudioUrl:audio)" controls></audio>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djqck/1/).

Comment: Thanks for responding, unfortunely I get the same result by using "ng-attr-src". The variable is not parsed into it's proper value.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle and found the actual error being thrown. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine with the hardcoded name of the files right in the controller, but what if I am getting the file names from a json object? As it is, in my application each event has it's own json object which in turn has it's own array of audio files. Is there a way to do the same in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately angular disallows interpolation in these cases...I played around with it and the best way I could find to do it was the pass the `audio` into a filter that does the escaping. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your input and some thinking around I solved it a different way, see my answer below. Thanks again for your responses!

Answer (score 3):

Hey FWIW i found this page looking for a solution to template URL's for my audio tag. However I am using multiple source tags for cross browser support:

```
<audio id="myAudioTag">
  <source ng-src="{{sceSoundUrlMp3}}">
  <source ng-src="{{sceSoundUrlOgg}}">
</audio>
```

First I solved SCE issues by whitelisting *.ogg, *.mp3: (keep 'self' otherwise your future requests fail)

```
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    "self",
    /(mp3|ogg)$/,
  ]);
})
```

This stopped giving SCE errors but Firefox reported 'no source' and didn't notice the `src` tag angular added.

The last step was to call load on the element after trusting and setting `$scope.sceSoundUrlMp3`: `$('#myAudioTag')[0].load()`

Answer (score 0):

I have used `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("/data/media/" + newVal)` but it didn't work.What seemed to work for me was to put  `document.getElementById('player').src = {{url}}`
in the controller

Hope that helps someone else.