# How to play a sound in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, audio

Using an API to obtain the url of the sound to play in audio tag
View

```
<img src="../img/play.svg" alt="Play" ng-click="playSound('exampleWord')" width="48"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.playSound=function(input){
    $scope.audio={};
    soundFetch.getSound(input).success(function(data){
        $scope.audio=data;
    });
}
```

The soundFetch is the service to call the getSound function. The returning data is the url of the song.
How can I play the sound after clicking the img tag. Currently getting an error `Error: [$interpolate:interr]`

Comment: `ng-click="playSound(word)"` remove `{{xx}}` from `{{word}}`

Comment: @PSL I have taken any word, even after that it`s not working.

Comment: there are a good answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659395/can-i-use-angular-variables-as-the-source-of-an-audio-tag Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
    $scope.playAudio = function() {
        var audio = new Audio('audio/song.mp3');
        audio.play();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var playSound = function(mp3File){
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElement.setAttribute('src', "/sound/"+mp3File);
  audioElement.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems playSound function takes input as argument

I'd try

`ng-click="playSound(this)"` or in the case of button

`ng-click="playSound(document.getElementById('audio'))"`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var audioFile = new Audio($scope.audioUrl); 
            audioFile.play();  //we can not get metadata until audio is fetched
            audioFile.pause(); //as soon as audio playes it pause so user does not hear a sound 

 audioFile.onplay = function () {
                audioFile.preload("metadata");         
            };

            audioFile.onloadedmetadata = function () {
                console.log(audioFile.duration);
                $scope.audioDuration = audioFile.duration;
            };
```

> when audio play method is called the  metadata are loaded