# Disabling Strict Contextual Escaping ($sce) in AngularJS not working for streaming audio

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, audio

I'm just trying to play / pause an audio streaming from elsewhere.

Initially I got an SCE error. Then found and tried solutions from different answers.
Those made the SCE error disappear, but the audio is still not working.

My first attempt was trying to use filters, following this aswwer: 
[AngularJS ng-src inside of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163152/angularjs-ng-src-inside-of-iframe)
I've added a filter in the app.js and chenged footer.html, as shown in the code commented out.

The second attempt was defining a trustedUrl() function, using $sce. (I've lost the reference)
I've changed the controller code and footer.html

The third attempt is the current code, trying to add the domain in a whitelist, following an answer from here:
[Angular $sce blocking my audio blob src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729537/angular-sce-blocking-my-audio-blob-src)

In the code below, apiURL, secret and factoryID are being faked - but the service is working fine.
My data object is being returned from the API with all the fields correct, already as an object (no need to parse json).
The sound streaming got from the API is the one I hardcoded in footer.html (as in the version 1 comment), and it worked well.

Some may suggest I move the audio control into a service, but my function toggleSound is also working. 
At least, the icons are toggling. I didn't try moving it, though.

I don't know why the result from ng-src seems to be empty in the html (I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place, but it won't show in the DOM structure).
Or audioElem.play() is not working - I don't know.

It seems to be so simple, but I can't make the audio streaming to play. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
I noticed one mistake: in the original question was using `this`wrong. I've already edited the code below, following this answer: [Using this within a promise in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903430/using-this-within-a-promise-in-angularjs)

The relevant parts of the code follow this structure:

**app.js:**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('radiogeek', [
    'ui.router', 
    'ngResource',
    'ngStorage'
])
.run(function () {
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {

    // attempt 3:
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'http://servidor30.brlogic.com:8270/Live'
    ]);
    // attempt 3

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url:'/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/header.html',
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/playing.html',
                    controller  : 'PlayingController'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/footer.html',
                    controller  : 'FooterController as footerCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})


.constant("baseURL","http://localhost:2000/")
.factory('APIFactory',['$http', function ($http) {

    var apiURL = "http://some.address.com/api/token";
    var secret = '87ac-a035-71ad-99fa-4509-95613-e3c6-adf';
    var factoryId = '48ad-81b5-c20fc-6ab7-5dcc-bda1-77bd626';

    var APIFactory = {};

    APIFactory.init = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: apiURL,
            data: JSON.stringify({"Maior":2,"Menor":0,"Build":0,"Revisao":0,"Usuario":"","Senha":"","Facebook":null}),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "secret": secret,
                "factoryId": factoryId,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    };

    return APIFactory;
}])    

/* attempt 1:
.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}])
*/

.controller('FooterController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$localStorage', '$sce', 'APIFactory' , 
function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, $localStorage, $sce, APIlFactory) {

    var playerIcon = false;
    var playerAction = 'Play';
    this.playerIcon = playerIcon;
    this.playerAction = playerAction;

    var self = this;
    APIFactory.init().then(
        function (response) {
            var data = response.data;

            // attempt 1
            //self.streamingUrl = data.streamingUrl;                        

            /* attempt 2
            self.trustedUrl = function(url) {
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
            }
            */

            self.streamingUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data.streamingUrl);

        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
        }
    );

    this.toggleSound = function() {
    var audioElem = document.getElementById('audio');
        if (audioElem.paused) {
            audioElem.play();
            self.playerIcon = true;
            self.playerAction = 'Pause';
        } else {
            audioElem.pause();
            self.playerIcon = false;
            self.playerAction = 'Play';
        }
    };
}]);
```

**footer.html:**

```
<div ng-click="footerCtrl.toggleSound();">
    <i class="material-icons css-align">{{!footerCtrl.playerIcon ? 'play_arrow' : 'stop'}}</i>
    <span class="css-align css-footer-span1">
      {{footerCtrl.playerAction}}
    </span>
</div>   
<audio id="audio">
    <!-- version 1: this was working fine:  -->
    <!--source src="http://servidor30.brlogic.com:8270/live" type="audio/mpeg"-->

    <!-- attempt 1: this didn't work -->
    <!--source ng-src="{{footerCtrl.streamingUrl | trustAsResourceUrl }}" type="audio/mpeg"-->

    <!-- attempt 2: this didn't work either:  -->
    <!--source ng-src="{{footerCtrl.trustedUrl(footerCtrl.streamingUrl)}" type="audio/mpeg"-->

    <!-- attempt 3: this didn't work either:  -->
    <source ng-src="{{footerCtrl.streamingUrl}}" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer here:
https://medium.com/kevins-daily-makers-academy-blog/html5-audio-and-angular-day-4-final-project-be0818239e8e

Basically, we have to move the `ng-src` into the `audio` tag:

```
<audio id="audio" ng-src="{{footerCtrl.streamingUrl}} type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And also, add the domain to the whitelist, in app.config:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'http://servidor30.brlogic.com/**'
]);
```

This was weird. There was an issue on Github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352